# AWS EBS include_once "Mail.php" not working

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pear

I have a php app on AWS EBS.Whenever I run it i get this error

> Warning: require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/current/index.php on line 3 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php7') in /var/app/current/index.php on line 3

The Line That Is causing problem is `require_once "Mail.php";`
I ran the command `$ pear config-get php_dir` and `$ which pear` i got responses `/usr/share/pear7` and `/usr/bin/pear` respectively.What Do i do? Before answering keep in mind that i can make changes only using aws console and ssh.

Comment: Sounds like you need to specify the path to `Mail.php`.

Comment: i tried that.with the info i provided can u tell what would be the path?